# LoadPicture error "invalid Picture" with ADO stream in VBA

Tags: vba

```vb
Private Sub btnCreate_Click()
    Dim objWinHttp As Object
    Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" + txtData.text + "&choe=UTF-8"

    objWinHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    objWinHttp.send ""
    SaveBinaryData "E:\Capture.bmp", objWinHttp.responseBody
End Sub


Function SaveBinaryData(FileName, Data)
    Const adTypeText = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Dim BinaryStream
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText
    BinaryStream.Open
    BinaryStream.Write Data
    BinaryStream.saveToFile FileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    BinaryStream.Close
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(FileName)
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [toir] and read [ask], then improve your question (edit)!

Comment: what is txtData.text?

Comment: txtData.text is text in the textbox